# I am getting the output is "the name and age of student is:null and 0" why?

Tags: java

```
public class student
{ 
    private String name,int age; 
    public student () 
    { 
        String name = "Dominic"; 
        int age = 10; 
    } 
    public String getName() 
    { 
        return name; 
    } 
    public int getAge() 
    { 
        return age; 
    } 
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        student s= new student();
        System.out.println("The name and age of employer is:");
        System.out.print(s.getName()+"\tand\t"+s.getAge());
    }
}
```

Comment: Short answer... In your constructor you are initializing *new local variables* instead of the class-level variables.  You never set the class-level ones.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the type declaration on the variables in the constructor. Your declaring a new variable name and age in the constructor by adding String and int

Change to

```
age = 10;
name = "Dominick";
```

This way your assigning the value to the class field not the local constructor variable. Also consider using this to specify the field.

```
this.age = 10;
this.name="Dominick";
```